# Have tried lots of solutions, but after changin Nvidia drivers now stuck in low graphics mode

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I've tried numerous solutions on here about getting out of low-graphics-mode on my Nvidia graphics but nothing seems to work. I'm thinking about completely re-loading the system from scratch, please tell me there is an easier solution as I have lots of data and don't want to re-load everything!  Slow computer with slow internet will take me forever..

Comment: Can you please describe what you tried? Like re-installing Open-Source drivers, installing official drivers from nVidia, official drivers from xorg PPA, changing your kernel, etc.
Please also add informations about your system (version of Ubuntu, your DE) and your graphic card model.

Comment: I double-post (sorry but it seemed necessary) : You can also reinstall Ubuntu without loosing your programs or your files. The Ubuntu live Installer offers that option, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me numerous times...
If you installed **nvidia-prime** then uninstall it

First click crtl+alt+f2(if that nothing happens then try a older kernel) then login and type:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia-prime nvidia-331 nvidia-331-updates nvidia-319 nvidia-319-updates nvidia-settings nvidia-settings-319
```

Then after run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Run autoremove in till there is nothing to remove then run

```
sudo reboot
```

And all should be well.

---

For **bumblebee**:

First click crtl+alt+f2(if that nothing happens then try a older kernel) then login and type:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove bumblebee* nvidia-331 nvidia-current nvidia-319  nvidia-331-updates nvidia-319-updates
```

and then to remove the ppa

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Run autoremove in till there is nothing to remove then run
Last

```
sudo reboot
```

And all should be well.